# Setup.py ignore PyPI package but still check for install

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I am creating a setup.py script for a package I have developed for my lab. I have run into an issue where the name for a local API we use mirrors the name of a package on PyPI.

The PyPI package is created by the same developers of the local API we use, but they decided to give both packages identical names (they claim its so they can be drop-in replacements even though the functionality is not the same). This is problematic when trying to list a dependency in setup.py since it will run
`pip install [package]` 
and it will install this remote package. Is there a way to tell setuptools to "ignore" a package that exists on PyPI, but still check that its installed so we can make sure that the API has been manually installed using `pip install -e .` before use?

I've considered using a try/except to attempt to import the local package and check some functionality or something to verify its the correct package, but that feels like a hack. The setup script works fine otherwise; I am just trying to properly check for this one local dependency. Would it be best to just instruct users to install the local API before use in the documentation?

Cheers!

Comment: The best would be to rename one of the packages.

Comment: @phd that was my thought exactly, but unfortunately I don't maintain either package. When I created an issue request on the repository they told me it was intentional...

Comment: Why list this this package in your project's dependencies at all? I have not understood this from reading your question.

Comment: @sinoroc This local API is integral to the function of the package, so I was under the impression these type of dependencies should be included in the setup.py file

Comment: Is this local library distributed on PyPI-like package repository? Maybe a private server (intranet)? -- How is this local library distributed and how is it meant to be installed? Via pip?

Comment: @sinoroc It is distributed in the installer of the software sold by this company. It is installed by navigating to the install directory and running `pip install -e .`

Comment: I see. -- The most important is to document things properly for the users. -- I would not remove the dependency on this 3rd party library. I would explain very clearly in the documentation of your package what the situation is and that the 3rd party library must be installed beforehand. The documentation should also make it clear that when "[whatever import error]" happens it is because the 3rd party library is not installed or it is the incorrect one that is installed. -- If you feel like it, you could add runtime logic to check that the correct 3rd party library is installed.

Comment: @sinoroc That makes sense and seems to be the most sensible way forward. Thank you for all the help!